# Parameters limit on intents

Tags: dialogflow-es, api-ai

On the intents there's a limitation of 20 parameters.

Why does this limit exists? Is there any way to use more than 20 entities in an intent?

Thanks!

Best whishes.

Answer (score 2):

The limit exists for processing speed and efficiency.

Depending on your exact needs, you may be able to create a [composite entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities#developer_composite).